# If $X=Y+Z$ and $X,Z$ are normal then is $Y$ also normal?

Tags: probability

> If $X=Y+Z$ and $X,Z$ are normal random variables then is $Y$ also normal?

This seems to be almost like [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_decomposition_theorem) but not quite as I don't assume independence.

Comment: Is $Y=0,$ a constant, a (degenerate) normal variable?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sure, allowing degeneracy.

Comment: Presumably , since Cramer’s theorem says that the two must be independent, there exists normal non-independent $U,V$ such that $U+V=W$ and $W$ is not normal. Then let $X=U,$ $Y=W, Z=-V.$ So you just need an example for why Cramer requires independence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks

Comment: You need something like the join normality.

Comment: @SangchulLee Sure...which is stronger than $Y$ being normal as jointly normal implies that $X-Z=Y$ is normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a standard normal and take $Z$ to be $X$ with probability $\frac12$ and $-X$ otherwise. This is also a standard normal.

However, $Y = X-Z$ is $0$ with probability $\frac12$ and $2X$ with probability $\frac12$, so it's definitely not normal!